# Sort a List<T> into List<List<T>> based on type using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I want to "sort" (not sure if that's the right terminology) a `List` based on an enum value inside the objects, where the `List` returned contains multiple `List`s, each containing objects with the same enum value.

ex:

```
class Obj {
    public MyEnum EnumVal { get; set; }
}

enum MyEnum {
    Val1, Val2, Val3
}

// Input
new List<Obj> {
    new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val1 },
    new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val1 },
    new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val2 },
    new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val3 },
    new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val1 },
    new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val3 },
    new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val2 },
    new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val3 }
}

// Output
new List<List<Obj>> {
    new List<Obj>{
        new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val1 },
        new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val1 },
        new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val1 }
    },
    new List<Obj>{
        new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val2 },
        new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val2 }
    },
    new List<Obj>{
        new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val3 },
        new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val3 },
        new Obj { EnumVal = MyEnum.Val3 }
    }
};
```

I know how to write a function that does this, but is there a way using Linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are talking about grouping, not sorting. you can do that with Linqs [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var grouped = input.GroupBy(x => x.EnumValue);
```

Comment: yes, thank you, I knew I was using the wrong terminology.

Comment: This is better than the `List<List<T>>`s, but if you actually need that, you can do: `input.GroupBy(x => x.EnumValue).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList()`.